# gtest EXPECT_CALL does not working when expected call is nested

Tags: c++, googletest

Look at such code snippet:

```
class Foo {
 public:
  Foo() {
  }

  void invoke_init(const int i) {
    init(i);
  }

 private:
  void init(const int i) {
    std::cout << "init " << i << std::endl;
  }
};
    
class MockedFoo : public Foo {
 public:
  MOCK_METHOD(void, init, (const int));
};

TEST(Foo, TestInitCalled) {
  MockedFoo mock;
  mock.invoke_init(1);
  EXPECT_CALL(mock, init(1));
}
```

As expected, `init()` is called and i see corresponding output. But the test is failed. Why? What is wrong there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Foo::init` needs to be **protected** instead of **private**. It also needs to be **virtual**.

Without `protected` as its visibility attribute, it can't really be overridden in the inherited class.  Without virtual, gmock can't do much with it either.

Instead of this:

```
 private:
  void init(const int i) {
    std::cout << "init " << i << std::endl;
  }
```

This:

```
 protected:
  virtual void init(const int i) {
    std::cout << "init " << i << std::endl;
  }
```

Comment: thanks! but for bring it to work also need to place `mock_invoke_init(1)` AFTER `EXPECT_CALL` and `protected` visibilty is not needed actually. The problem was that method was not virtual.

Comment: Good call out on swapping the lines. But I'm at a complete loss to explain how leaving `Foo::init` private in the base class enables for it to inherited in the `MockedFoo`. Doesn't make sense.

Comment: Hm, why it is strange in your mind?) private virtual function can be overloaded in derived classes in c++ as i know.

Comment: I think you are right.  I just had a brain fart thinking if the visibility of the method is hidden in the derived class, it couldn't be overridden.